# Compare two organizational units with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ou

I would like to compare two organizational units users.
I can get my user list with this command:

```
OU_NUMBER_1:

Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=OU_NUMBER_1,OU=OU-SNE_SharePoint,DC=vf,DC=local" | Select sAMAccountName


OU_NUMBER_2:
    Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=OU_NUMBER_2,OU=OU-SNE_SharePoint,DC=vf,DC=local" | Select sAMAccountName
```

I would like to get homonymous from these lists. Do I have to put my users in some lists and compare them ? Or anyone get a better idea ?

To summary, I would like to get a list with homonymous of my OU's.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking to get the users that are in both OUs?

Comment: yes, it's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

**/Update**

Try

```
$UserGroup1 = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=OU_NUMBER_1,OU=OU-SNE_SharePoint,DC=vf,DC=local" | select sAMAccountName


$UserGroup2 = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=OU_NUMBER_2,OU=OU-SNE_SharePoint,DC=vf,DC=local" | Select sAMAccountName


$UserInBothOU = Compare-Object $UserGroup1 $UserGroup2 -IncludeEqual
```

Be aware that the Array `$UserInBothOU` contains PowerShell Objects.
When you want the sAMAccountName, then you must do something like that:

```
foreach($User in $UserInBothOU)
{
    Write-host $User.sAMAccountName
}
```

Because sAMAccountName is only an attribute.

Comment: I have tested your solution.

But I can't get any user in my $UserInBothGroups

Even if I change my PS code with this, nothing is contained in it:

Foreach($User in $UserGroup1)
{
        [Array]$UserInBothGroups += $User
}

Comment: Please try out my update.
If this even doesn't work, you have to wait until tomorrow, when I am at work :)

Comment: Thank you ! I'll test tomorrow at work too and I'll keep you in touch ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$OLDGroup = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=InactiveObjects,DC=gov,DC=au" -server "gov.au" | select sAMAccountName

$NEWGroup = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=StandardUsers,OU=Users,DC=nsw,DC=gov,DC=au" -server "nsw.gov.au" | Select sAMAccountName

compare-object $OLDGroup $NEWGroup -Property 'SamAccountName' -IncludeEqual
```